# AngularJS controller does not run on RequireJS config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to configure an web app with requireJS and angularJS. I come from marionette configuration and I am trying to have a similar one in angular (in concepts like views and controllers) first so I want to be able to map #/test to my controller and log in the console one message.

I've seen [Does AngularJS support AMD like RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108207/does-angularjs-support-amd-like-requirejs/21052364#21052364) and [RequireJS and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056502/requirejs-and-angularjs) and I kind of got the differences and from my point of view my config should work... but it does not...

Here is my code:

File: app.config.js

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        angularRoute: ['angular']
    },
    paths: {
        angular: '../lib/angular',
        angularRoute: '../lib/angular-route'
    }
});

require(['angular', 'app', 'routes/index'], function (angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

File: app.js

```
define(['angular', 'angularRoute'], function (angular) {
    //angular.module('app.controllers', []);
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    return app;
});
```

File: routes/index.js

```
define(['angular', 'app', 'controllers/index'], function (angular, app) {
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: require.toUrl('/resources/js/app/templates/test.html'), controller: 'indexController'});
    }]);
});
```

File: controllers/index.js

```
define(['angular', 'app'], function (angular, app) {
    //var appControllers = angular.module('app.controllers');
    app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log('cascade...');
    }]);
});
```

What am i missing? When i access #/test, i don't see "cascade" in the console, should I?.. Right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao It does not show "cascade" in the console. It means that the controller does not get called?

Comment: Can you post the html you are calling the require and the controller?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao This one https://goo.gl/GGiZ9Z this file does not show on network tab in chrome dev tools