# Angularjs: lazy versus requirements based loading

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-directive, modernizr

I see ways I can lazy load Angularjs from these articles:
    http://roubenmeschian.com/rubo/?p=40 and
    http://ify.io/entry/172/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

In practice I see most use out of more simple requirement based loading in directives, like this example:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/angular-1.0.6/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/script.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

.....

.directive('myDesktopDatepickerDirective', function() {
    return {
        link : function($scope,$element) {
            if(Modernizr.isDesktop) {
                $script([
                    'js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js'
                ],function() {
                    $element.datepicker();
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Under what circumstances would you want to do an application level lazy load of Angular, detailed in these articles, as well as a requirements based example like the one I have above?

Comment: To clarify- my question is- why do lazy loading of Angular at it's app level?

Comment: Another article on integrating Angular with requirejs: http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/

Comment: This post pretty answers my question, thx

[Does it make sense to use Require.js with Angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529083/does-it-make-sense-to-use-require-js-with-angular-js)