# AngularJS resource management

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm including several items for my Angular app.

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/oneCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/twoCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/threeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/oneSvc.js"></script>
<script src="js/twoSvc.js"></script>
<script src="js/threeSvc.js"></script>
etc...
```

Are all those files loaded into memory at page load or does angular manage loading those resources into memory as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define them as script tags, your browser will load them all, Angular has no control over this. If you want a system where you conditionally load scripts you should look at RequireJS / AMD. ( Maybe [RequireJS with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529083/does-it-make-sense-to-use-require-js-with-angular-js) might be what you're looking for. )