# implementation of angularjs with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to implement angularjs with requirejs

Here is my applicaiton.js file which loads initially

```
var config = {
    baseUrl: '/assets/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        twitter: 'twitter',
        angular: 'angular',
        angularjs: 'angularjs',       # This is the directory
        app: 'app'
    },
    shim: {
        'twitter/bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config(config);

requirejs(['jquery', 'twitter/bootstrap', 'angularjs/app', 'app/common']);
```

**Directory structure**

```
Application.js
Angularjs/
    -controllers/
    -directives/
    -Services/
    -app.js
```

As startup angularjs/app.js will be initiated and my app.js contains

```
define('app', ['angular'], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    return app;
})

require(['app'], function(app) {
    app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'hello';
    })
})
```

While running getting the exception as

**Failed to instantiate module app**

Used [this as reference link](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/04/integrating-angularjs-with-requirejs/)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a healthy way to use RequireJS aside from the fact that does not work. Please refer to my answer regarding using RequireJS with AngularJS: [Does it make sense to use Require.js with Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529083/does-it-make-sense-to-use-require-js-with-angular-js/20954143#20954143)