# The very simplest way to "require" or "import" to modularise javascript ASP.Net MVC 5, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

All I would like to do is to be able to modularise my javascript/jquery/ajax client-side code, to use some existing library code which I have written and now want to use in the scripts section of my pages -  using something simple like in Node "require" or ES6 "import" syntax.

[ASP.Net MVC 5, Visual Studio 2015]

In webpage:

```
@section scripts
{

    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Views/Items/Index.js")

}
```

In Index.js:

```
$(function ()
{
    var myLib = require("../Shared/my-lib");
```

OR

```
$(function ()
{
   import * from "../Shared/my-lib";
```

In my-lib.js:

```
export var myFunction1 = myFunction1;
export var myFunction2 = myFunction2;
```

I am an experienced .NETter but a bit of a js noob, so if I am missing anything utterly obvious, please tell me kindly! I just want to keep it DRY, you know?

I tried just doing it as above but it throws syntax errors about either "import" or "require", so I figure it doesn't just work out of the box.

I've looked up Browserify and RequireJS - but that seems like a TON of fiddly setup (yeah i am fine with npm but it is all the settings files, build files, specific way of writing the library code ... etc. etc.) - do I really have to do all that just to "include"/ import some code?

Should I write my library as OO javascript? Would that help?

At the moment I am just doing:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/Shared/my-lib.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/Item/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which doesn't strike me as very elegant...

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how many files you are going to maintain and dependencies between those files. If this is just about a few files then you can simply include them as you already do and put the repeated code into JS module (of course in order) to keep your code DRY.

e.g.

```
var myLib = (function(){
    var privateVar = 1;

    var method1 = function(){
    };
    // export
    return {
        method1: method1
    }
})();
```

Also, using jQuery you can always load your JavaScript conditionally if you need so using [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) so you can load only particular JS file depending on your current page route, name etc.

***If however*** we are talking about more JS files (even with only 10 files/JS modules the maintaining of project can become pretty hard if you consider more complicated dependencies scenario such as *file1* depends on *file2*, *file4* on *file3* and *file2* etc.). In this case it is definitely worth to invest your time into some [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) framework such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Other frameworks such as Angular have their own [modularization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) features and these can actually live together with *RequireJS* as was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529083/does-it-make-sense-to-use-require-js-with-angular-js).

Also, very often project seems to be simple at the beginning but then grows unexpectedly fast. It's up to you to decide though.

You can also consider some existing [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RequireJsNet/) packages such as [RequireJS.Net](http://requirejsnet.veritech.io/setup.html) to help you with integration into ASP.NET MVC project.

Btw. In terms of the `import` and `export` - as stated in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import):

> Note: This feature is not implemented in any browsers natively at this
>   time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur
>   Compiler, Babel or Rollup.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had found comments that import/export wasn't natively supported but I wasn't sure how up to date that information was (I was hoping ti had improved!!).  There's a bit of faff to using RequireJS (if I recall my researches the other day correctly), but I guess I might have to give it (or something similar) a go...